# Trying to get list apps from system tray

Tags: c#, system-tray

hello I am Trying to get list apps from system tray

```
IntPtr systemTrayHandle = GetSystemTrayHandle();

UInt32 count = User32.SendMessage(systemTrayHandle, TB.BUTTONCOUNT, 0, 0);

ArrayList tbButtons = new ArrayList();
List<TBBUTTON> tbButtons2 = new List<TBBUTTON>();

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    TBBUTTON tbButton = new TBBUTTON();
    string text = String.Empty;
    IntPtr ipWindowHandle = IntPtr.Zero;

    bool b = GetTBButton(systemTrayHandle, i, ref tbButton, ref text, ref ipWindowHandle);
    if (tbButton.dwData != 0)
    {
        tbButtons.Add(tbButton);
        tbButtons2.Add(tbButton);
    }
}
```

The problem is I only get two buttons. the internet and the volume button

after i try Automation i get only 2 buttons same buttons :-(
here img
https://i.stack.imgur.com/q9JUi.jpg

Comment: What are `GetSystemTrayHandle()` and `GetTBButton()`?  They don't appear to be part of any Windows API.

Comment: Found that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34102114/tray-button-handles-in-windows-10 & https://windows-hexerror.linestarve.com/q/so33652756-How-to-get-the-processes-that-have-systray-icon & https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4c4f60ce-3573-433d-994e-9c17f95187f0/finding-which-applications-and-services-are-listed-in-the-system-tray?forum=csharpgeneral & http://delphidabbler.com/tips/47

Comment: Look into `Automation` namespace. Also I did something like this a bit ago [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40007156/1797425)

Comment: Olivier Rogier I tried exactly the guides you sent and I only get two buttons and now I tried with Çöđěxěŕ's offer with Automation I only get two buttons again :-((

Comment: BACON i build my app like this https://windows-hexerror.linestarve.com/q/so33652756-How-to-get-the-processes-that-have-systray-icon